# ToggleClass on anchor tag but the link does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have (I suppose) a pretty simple question but I cannot find the solution myself.

I have an overlay menu with a few menu items, a cancel button and also you can exit the menu by clicking outside the nav element. The problem is that the menu disappears as expected after adding appropriate jQuery code to remove some classes and make the menu invisible, the anchor tags do not seem to work (the menu items)...

Those links indicate separate sections of the same page (within the same HTML) and as you click on a certain li, it should take you to assigned to it section, e.g. blog, which has html:

```
<div id="blog"> ... </div>
```

Menu HTML:

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <a href="#" id="close-btn"> X </a>
    <nav class="display" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="activable" href="#diamond-row"> Photos </a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog" class="activable"> Blog </a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="activable"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#close-btn, a.activable').click(function() {
        $('.nav-container').toggleClass('active');
        $('.cover').toggleClass('active-cover');
        $('.scroll-down').toggleClass('hidden');
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click", "div:not('.nav-container')",function() {
    $('.cover').removeClass('active-cover');
    $('.nav-container').removeClass('active');
    $('.scroll-down').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.cover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.active-cover {
    visibility: visible;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Is it related to toggleClass instead of addClass and removeClass? I am going to test it now.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour of those links as they are just hashes?

Comment: @Ishettyl: I was only testing it with the first one (#diamond-row) and did not add the rest. It is corrected now

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question I asked!

Comment: Instead of pointing it out maybe you should clarify it @Ishettyl? Hence I have to guess what you meant: those links are on the same page and indicate separate sections of the page and as you click on a certain li, it should take you to assigned to it section, e.g. blog (which has html: <div id="blog"> ... </div>)

Comment: do you have anywhere on the same html page <a name="diamond-row"></a>?

Comment: @Niralana actually we all have to guess what you have on the page. First off, you should have added your reply to my last comment to your question which actually helps all of us save some time assuming whether or not you have proper ref's to those anchors.

Comment: @Niralana, in short -  link that you have will work only for the same page, they won't go to the div with this id(you may confuse #name with #id from css - this is not the same things). Those link will lead you only to the <a name="you_link_name"></a> section ON THE SAME PAGE. If you want to load different pages, you need to use different links, like "http://youdomain.com/page_you_need.html" or "/page_you_need.html"

Comment: @Niralana, It would be great if you can create fiddle for the same on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Also, try removing `return false;` as it makes no sense there.

Comment: I didn't have <a name="#diamond-row"></a> @metamorph_online, I have added it to the HTML but it still does not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ishettyl - it works after removing "return false;"

Comment: It's `<a name="diamond-row"></a>`. Note, no hash in the name attribute value!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/am8hkdy9/1/ - yes, you needed to remove "return" as it ended the function before default click action fired, I guess